# How do I make the local planner rotate in place?

Tags: ros, navigation, baseglobalplanner, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I get the local planner to turn in place and then head towards a goal instead of moving forward and turning at the same time? I am facing issues when the robot is able to reach a goal but cannot come back to the same point by doing a turn in place and following a similar global plan.  The local planner tries to make the robot move forward and turn. But it then comes too close to an obstacle and get stuck.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215758/how-do-i-make-the-local-planner-rotate-in-place?/) by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2015-08-12

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on 2016-03-17**:
Does anyone have a suggestion about this please? It would be really helpful.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-17**:
If you have a comment please post it as a comment; not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your robot gets too close to obstacles, you should figure out why it's doing that; not try to force complicated heuristics on the planner.

You may want to adjust your footprint or the obstacle distance bias in the local planner.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on 2016-03-17**:
Thanks for your answer. The problem is not that it is getting too close to obstacles but when working in confined spaces, I would like to prevent the robot from doing large translations when trying to rotate to avoid collisions. Which is the obstacle distance bias parameter for trajectory rollout?

**Comment by [DanThe](https://answers.ros.org/users/24985/danthe/) on 2016-03-19**:
Just in case it is helpful to anyone, in the parameters for TrajectoryPlannerROS - setting the occdist_scale parameter to a value higher than the default value, helps to control the turning radius of the robot.

**Comment by [felipeduque](https://answers.ros.org/users/49885/felipeduque/) on 2020-05-04**:
Indeed. I set occdist to 0.1 (from default 0.05) and the robot preferred to rotate in place longer before moving.